# form validation + ajax issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have a registration form , I'm using ajax

```
< form id="form" class="form" action="form.php" method="post" >
```

In `form.php` when I click button register the validations happens in form 
like if username exists and password match then it registers  it all works fine in form.php but for ajax i had to create another page `check.php` which also checks user existence if `ajaxusername = username` then it returns user exist in front of the username field which is ok but when i press register it register the user even if the user exists.

I have used ajax :

```
     ---------------- form . php -------------

    function aj(){
    $("document").ready(function (){

    var username = $("#username").val();


    $.ajax({
      url: 'check.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {ajaxusername:username},

      success: function(data) {
        $('#existu').html(data);
        }
      });


            });
    };



  <?php
 session_start();
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","","db") or 
 die(mysql_error());

 if(isset($_POST['register'])){
 $name=$_POST['username'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 $confirmpassword=$_POST['confirmpassword'];

 $q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM userreg WHERE username='$name'");
 $query="INSERT INTO regform(username,email,password,confirmpassword) 
 VALUES('$name','$email','$password','$confirmpassword')";

 if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0){

 $userexist="User already exists!";

 }
elseif ($password==$confirmpassword){


  mysqli_query($con,$query);
  $a=header("location:welcome.php");

 }
 else{

 $error="Password does not match!";

}

}





 ?>
```

check.php

---

```
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","","db") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['ajaxusername'])){
$query="SELECT * FROM userreg WHERE username='".$_POST["ajaxusername"]."'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
echo "exist";
}
else 
{
echo "does not exist";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Show us check.php that is where the problem is

Comment: please edit your question and place this code with the question

Comment: i edited it @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: and your registration? you only checking here

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i have 2 pages one is form.php and other is check.php if user registers fine it goes to welcome.php .. i edited again my post please check form.php

Comment: if you want to register via ajax then, register through ajax here you can do first in ajax call check.php if user exist then just show user exist else in the same received response call a ajax and save sata.

Comment: You can do everything in that check.php page no need for two files`echo "does not exist";` put your registration there

Comment: I made changes in form,check.php in if condition if data=="exist" then value becomes empty "" of text field else it retains the value & in php , if mysqli_num_rows returning 1 then i encoded the data in jason like echo jason encode("exist"); that way it worked ..   my question is if it is proper way to create a registration form or not ?